# Trait with type-dependent optional function forces implementation regardless of type

Tags: rust

In my minimal example, I would like to create a trait `MyTrait<T>` that provides a function `do_member` **if and only if** `T` implements `Doable`.

Here is my first attempt, which fails, complaining that the function needs to be implemented:

```rust
trait Doable {}

trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn set_member(&mut self, member: T);

    fn do_member(&mut self)
    where
        T: Doable;
}

struct MyMember;
struct MyTraitStruct(Option<MyMember>);

impl MyTrait<MyMember> for MyTraitStruct {
    fn set_member(&mut self, member: MyMember) {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `do_member`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:1
   |
6  | /     fn do_member(&mut self)
7  | |     where
8  | |         T: Doable;
   | |__________________- `do_member` from trait
...
14 |   impl MyTrait<MyMember> for MyTraitStruct {
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `do_member` in implementation

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0046`.
```

However, when I do try to add said function, as suggested, it fails with the error that it cannot implement that function for the given type:

```rust
trait Doable {}

trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn set_member(&mut self, member: T);

    fn do_member(&mut self)
    where
        T: Doable;
}

struct MyMember;
struct MyTraitStruct(Option<MyMember>);

impl MyTrait<MyMember> for MyTraitStruct {
    fn set_member(&mut self, member: MyMember) {
        todo!()
    }

    // It forces me to add this implementation although
    // `MyMember` is not `Doable`. How do I work around this?
    fn do_member(&mut self)
    where
        MyMember: Doable,
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MyMember: Doable` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:23:9
   |
23 |         MyMember: Doable,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Doable` is not implemented for `MyMember`
   |
   = help: see issue #48214

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

What's the solution here? Split the trait into two parts?

Comment: Slightly suboptimal but can't you add a default implementation `fn do_member(&mut self) { unimplemented!() }` in the trait?

Comment: @cafce25 Yah, that is one thought I had as well, but that means that when users implement the trait they don't get reminded to implement that function if needed.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't force the `where` on your implementation so this compiles and does what you want even though it's admittedly a bit ugly to have to add an uncallable method implementation:

```rust
trait Doable {}

trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn set_member(&mut self, member: T);

    fn do_member(&mut self)
    where
        T: Doable;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyMember;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyTraitStruct(Option<MyMember>);

impl MyTrait<MyMember> for MyTraitStruct {
    fn set_member(&mut self, member: MyMember) {
        println!("{self:?} {member:?}");
    }
    fn do_member(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut mts = MyTraitStruct(None);
    mts.set_member(MyMember);
    // mts.do_member(); -> error MyMember: Doable not satisfied
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12598db7b5d01ae51da170968f47ac3a)

Comment: Ha. I didn't know that you can simply leave out the `where`.

Comment: Not sure if I should mark this as the accepted answer. It does fix the problem that I was having, but it feels more like a hack than a proper solution.

Comment: Yea definitely more a workaround for something the language should be able to figure out.

Comment: Probably a duplicate but I've not found anything so I created an [issue for it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/110219)